# cloudwatch metric Filter Pattern doesn't match with the json logs

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I am trying to configure a custom metric for my service which will monitor the uptime of the service, I am trying to get the value of status code and raise an alarm if the value is 4* and 5* I am trying to match the statusCode using json filter patter but not able to get it correct

```
 {
        "res": {
            "statusCode": 500
        },
        "req": {
            "url": "",
            "headers": {
                "host": "",
                "connection": "close",
                "user-agent": "",
                "accept-encoding": "gzip, compressed"
            },
            "method": "GET",
            "httpVersion": "1.1",
            "originalUrl": "",
            "query": {}
        },
        "responseTime": 1,
        "requestId": "",
        "level": "info",
        "message": "",
        "timestamp": ""
    }
```

my filter pattern is 
I tried these both but none of them worked
**{$.res.statusCode = 500}**

**{($.res.statusCode = 2*)||($.res.statusCode = 5*)}**

I am trying to follow https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html

Comment: I have this issue to. I even tried to use the example json data from the link you provided and when i use the filter pattern they use, it gives 0 matches.

Comment: @Moddaman see the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be the issue with json when we copy paste the json doesn't work,
if selected from **Log Data to Test** dropdown , the filter worked for me in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that worked for me is the one in, [AWS Cloudwatch Json Metric Filter Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52059922/aws-cloudwatch-json-metric-filter-pattern)

which quotes,

> When using the Test Metric Filter feature in the AWS Console, each log
>   event has to be in a separate line. You can still run the same test,
>   but you have to remove all new lines from the sample data.