# AWS Cloudwatch Json Metric Filter Pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

Following [the Amazon Example for Json Metric Filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html),
I tried to copy their example. In the process of creating a metric filter, you can test it with example logs first. So I went for "Custom Log",
copy-pasted the example from the link given above:

```
{
  "eventType": "UpdateTrail",
  "sourceIPAddress": "111.111.111.111",
  "arrayKey": [
        "value",
        "another value"
  ],
  "objectList": [
       {
         "name": "a",
         "id": 1
       },
       {
         "name": "b",
         "id": 2
       }
  ],
  "SomeObject": null,
  "ThisFlag": true
}
```

and my pattern is: `{ $.eventType = "UpdateTrail" }`  as stated in the example

This is the output of "Test Pattern":

> Found 0 matches out of 20 event(s) in the sample log.

How to use them correctly? I seem to not quite grasp the concept.

**Update from my side**: It seems to have problems with line breaks, for my own purposes I just put my entire custom json into one line which is published by `logger.info(json.dumps(my_message))`.
I put this "fix" here in case someone stumbles upon the same problem.
I'd still like to hear a general solution!

Answer (score 9):

When using the Test Metric Filter feature in the AWS Console, each log event has to be in a separate line. You can still run the same test, but you have to remove all new lines from the sample data.